# ruby ri: Nothing known about Array

Tags: 11.10, ruby, documentation

There doesn't seem to be any ri documentation on core ruby classes on my system. Using `ri -c` I see that there are docs for a few gems I've installed, but that's it.

```
$ ri Array
Nothing known about Array
```

I'm using the standard system ruby1.8 (1.8.7.352-2). I'm not using rvm. Is there some other package I need to install? On a very similar machine (also Oneiric with ruby 1.8) `ri Array` works just fine, and I can't tell what the difference is.

`ruby -v` on the problematic machine:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

and on the normal machine:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Can you add the full output of `ruby -v` on both machines to your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo and behold, there is a package. In my defense, there are so many hits for `aptitude search ri` that I didn't see it.

```
apt-get install ri1.8
```